# How to convert a matrix to dictionary like a list?

Tags: r

I have a matrix like:

```
> mat
  name  path
1   A  A.csv
2   B  B.csv
3   C  C.csv
```

and I want to convert it to dictionary-like list as:

```
> list("A"="A.csv", "B"="B.csv", "C"="C.csv")
$A
[1] "A.csv"

$B
[1] "B.csv"

$C
[1] "C.csv"
```

I'd appreciate if anyone let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple, just use `as.list` to convert the second column to a list and then set the names with `names`

```
l <- as.list(mat[,"path"])
names(l)<-mat[,"name"]
```

Comment: Better to use `mat[,"path"]`. It is safer and will work with matrices.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Right, I was thinking it was a dataframe instead of a matrix. I'll change that

Comment: I suspect it's a DF though because there are no quotes on OP's `mat` output.